# Connection strings not available from App.Config in Unit Tests run on TFS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfs-2015

I'v some DB facing unit tests that take their connection string from an app.config file. I'm grabbing the strings thru **ConfigurationManager** class.

```
var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
```

The tests run fine on dev machine but not on TFS. There is a null refernce error. If I jsut replace the connection string in unit test with a hard coded string - identical to that in app.config - then the test works. Oh yeah, and I've made sure that app.config is set to "copy to output folder".

Is there a known issue with TFS and ConfigurationManager?

pom

Comment: Can you show your code where you are trying to get the connection string?

Comment: @P.Jairai: that is the code up in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same problem with TFS 2015 (on premises with update 2).  We have multiple test projects that access a connection string from the app.config file however one particular project failed to access the connection string which caused our build to fail.

I altered the .csproj file to match other working test projects but this didn't provide any success, instead the following worked for me:

1. Copied the contents of the App.config to notepad
2. Deleted the App.config file from the project
3. Added a new Application Configuration File (App.config) to the project
4. Pasted the contents from notepad into the new App.confg file
5. Right click the App.config file and altered its properties:

   - Build Action: Content
   - Copy to output directory: Copy always

Upon check-in all unit tests within the project passed successfully.

It's an odd solution but it got our tests running.

> Note: Deleting the App.config file was a necessary step.  Changing the properties on the file (prior to deleting the file) didn't make a difference.

## Update:

After applying the above solution I noticed all unit tests were running twice and after some investigation I discovered the entire issue was down to our build configuration: -

- On our Visual Studio Build task we use the following parameter on our MS Build Arguments:

  `/p:OutDir=$(Build.StagingDirectory)`
- Our Visual Studio Test task was configured to look for Test Assembly in the following location:

  `**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`

Altering the Test Assembly location to the following fixed everything:

`$(Build.StagingDirectory)\*test*.dll;-:**\_PublishedWebsites\**`

No more issues with App.config files and unit tests ran once only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I made another test project in my solution and added the app.config there again with the conn strings and now it works also on TFS. I don't know what the cause was but I'll leave the question here for possible reference and solution for others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My Test project is a separate project from the main project.  Therefore it needs its own copy of App.config.  Follow the steps in previous response to add new Application Configuration file and give it the same contents as in your main project.

Comment: welcome to SO.  "in previous response" is a bit vague, what steps are refering the OP to follow?